# How to unzip files with same name in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of zip folders in a directory that I am trying to unzip with VBA. I am using the following code:

```
Sub UnzipAll()
    Dim oShell As Object: Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Dim folder As Variant:  folder = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\")

    While (folder <> "")
        If InStr(folder, ".zip") > 0 Then
            oShell.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\").CopyHere oShell.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\" & folder).Items
        End If
    folder = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

This works just fine, but runs into a problem: when two zip folders contain a file with the same name, a prompt pops up asking if I want to replace or keep both.

How can I make it so that it extracts both files, keeping both? Maybe putting a number after one to differentiate?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not, before copying the file, check the file names in the folder (perhaps put them in an array), and if a name matches, add your number to the end of the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is a total shot in the dark, but this *might* work. I'm just not familiar with this `.Namespace` or `.CopyHere` syntax, but I think this would work (appending a number to the end of files that already exist at the location).

```
Sub UnzipAll()
    Dim oShell As Object: Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Dim folder As Variant:  folder = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\")
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    While (folder <> "")

        If InStr(folder, ".zip") > 0 Then
            If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\" & oShell.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\" & folder).Items) = "" Then
                oShell.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\").CopyHere oShell.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\" & folder).Items
            Else
                oShell.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\").CopyHere oShell.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\" & folder).Items & i
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If

        folder = Dir

    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch when that happens. I don't think Dir() can be used twice like this

Comment: @Kos What does `oShell.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Attachments\" & folder).Items` return? A filename?